# Unable to insert data in mysql table

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, insert

I am not able to insert product and also alert script is not working. I'm trying to insert some data into my database using a form. After filling the form I am taking data using method="POST". I have no syntax errors, although I can't insert the data from my form to my database.

```
<?php
    include("includes/db.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.3/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#999999">
        <form method="post" action="insert_product.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table width="700" align="center" border="1" bgcolor="#0099CC">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td colspan="2"><h1>Insert New Product:</h1></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Title</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product_title" size="50"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Category</b></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="product_cat">
                            <option>Select a Category</option>
                            <?php
                                $get_cats = "select * from categories";
                                $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);
                                while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
                                    $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
                                    $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
                                    echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Brand</b></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="product_brand">
                            <option>Select Brand</option>
                            <?php
                                $get_brands = "select * from brands";
                                $run_brands = mysqli_query($con, $get_brands);
                                while ($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){
                                    $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
                                    $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title'];
                                    echo "<option value='$brand_id'>$brand_title</option>";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Image 1</b></td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="product_img1"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Image 2</b></td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="product_img2"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Image 3</b></td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="product_img3"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Price</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product_price"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Description</b></td>
                    <td><textarea name="product_desc"cols="35" rows="10"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Keywords</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product_keywords" size="50"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="Insert Product" value="Insert Product"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php        
    if (isset($_POST['insert_product'])){
        //text data variables
        $product_title =$_POST['product_title'];
        $product_cat =$_POST['product_cat'];
        $product_brand =$_POST['product_brand'];
        $product_price =$_POST['product_price'];
        $product_desc =$_POST['product_desc'];
        $status = 'on';
        $product_keywords =$_POST['product_keywords'];

        //image names
        $product_img1 = $_FILES['product_img1']['name'];
        $product_img2 = $_FILES['product_img2']['name'];
        $product_img3 = $_FILES['product_img3']['name'];

        //Image temp names
        $temp_name1 = $_FILES['product_img1']['tmp_name'];
        $temp_name2 = $_FILES['product_img2']['tmp_name'];
        $temp_name3 = $_FILES['product_img3']['tmp_name'];

        if($product_title=='' OR $product_cat=='' OR $product_brand=='' OR $product_price=='' OR $product_desc=='' OR $product_keywords=='' OR $product_img1==''){
            echo "<script>alert('Please fill all the fields!')</script>";
            exit();
        } else {
            //uploading images to its folder
            move_uploaded_file($temp_name1,"product_images/$product_img1");
            move_uploaded_file($temp_name2,"product_images/$product_img2");
            move_uploaded_file($temp_name3,"product_images/$product_img3");

            $insert_product = "insert into products (cat_id,brand_id,date,product_title,product_img1,product_img2,product_img3,product_price,product_desc,status) values ('$product_cat','$product_brand',NOW(),'$product_title','$product_img1','$product_img2','$product_img3','$product_price','$product_desc','status')";

            $run_product = mysqli_query($con,$insert_product);
            if($run_product){
                echo "<script>alert('Product inserted successfully')</script>";
            }   
        }   
    }
?>
```

Comment: You aren't checking for SQL errors. You are open to SQL injections.

Comment: try to print only query i.e.    `echo $insert_product`

and let me know what you are getting....

Comment: `Insert Product`!=`insert_product` => `name="Insert Product"` vs `$_POST['insert_product']`. Your submit name in your form does not match your php `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

just one line mistake.Replace

```
 <input type="submit" name="insert_product" value="Insert Product"/>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="insert_product" value="Insert Product"/>
```

Since you have checked if(isset($_POST[insert_product])). Try the code

```
<?php
include("includes/db.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.3/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#999999">
<form method="post" action="insert_product.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="700" align="center" border="1" bgcolor="#0099CC">
<tr align="center">
<td colspan="2"><h1>Insert New Product:</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>Product Title</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="product_title" size="50"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>Product Category</b></td>
<td>
<select name="product_cat">
<option>Select a Category</option>
<?php
    $get_cats = "select * from categories";
    $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);
    while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
        $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
        $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
    echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>";
    }
    ?>

</select>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>Product Brand</b></td>
<td>
<select name="product_brand">
<option>Select Brand</option>
<?php
    $get_brands = "select * from brands";
    $run_brands = mysqli_query($con, $get_brands);
    while ($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){
        $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
        $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title'];
    echo "<option value='$brand_id'>$brand_title</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>Product Image 1</b></td>
<td><input type="file" name="product_img1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>Product Image 2</b></td>
<td><input type="file" name="product_img2"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>Product Image 3</b></td>
<td><input type="file" name="product_img3"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>Product Price</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="product_price"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>Product Description</b></td>
<td><textarea name="product_desc"cols="35" rows="10"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><b>Product Keywords</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="product_keywords" size="50"/></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="insert_product" value="Insert Product"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['insert_product'])){
    //text data variables
    $product_title =$_POST['product_title'];
    $product_cat =$_POST['product_cat'];
    $product_brand =$_POST['product_brand'];
    $product_price =$_POST['product_price'];
    $product_desc =$_POST['product_desc'];
    $status = 'on';
    $product_keywords =$_POST['product_keywords'];


    //image names

    $product_img1 = $_FILES['product_img1']['name'];
    $product_img2 = $_FILES['product_img2']['name'];
    $product_img3 = $_FILES['product_img3']['name'];

    //Image temp names
    $temp_name1 = $_FILES['product_img1']['tmp_name'];
    $temp_name2 = $_FILES['product_img2']['tmp_name'];
    $temp_name3 = $_FILES['product_img3']['tmp_name'];

    if($product_title=='' OR $product_cat=='' OR $product_brand=='' OR $product_price=='' OR $product_desc=='' OR $product_keywords=='' OR $product_img1==''){
        echo "<script>alert('Please fill all the fields!')</script>";
        exit();
        }
     else {
    //uploading images to its folder
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name1,"product_images/$product_img1");
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name2,"product_images/$product_img2");
    move_uploaded_file($temp_name3,"product_images/$product_img3");

    $insert_product = "insert into products (cat_id,brand_id,date,product_title,product_img1,product_img2,product_img3,product_price,product_desc,status) values ('$product_cat','$product_brand',NOW(),'$product_title','$product_img1','$product_img2','$product_img3','$product_price','$product_desc','status')";

    $run_product = mysqli_query($con,$insert_product);
    if($run_product){
        echo "<script>alert('Product inserted successfully')</script>";

        }   
    }   
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button name is not same as your isset($_POST['insert_product']) statement.